# How to write text on top of image in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to display a image on canvas and insert a text on top of that image.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
    };

    imageObj.src = "darth-vader.jpg";
    context.font = "40pt Calibri";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);
};
```

I'm getting only an image over here but not the text; the text is behind the image.
How to insert the text on top of the image?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That is because you draw the text before the image has loaded and been drawn. You have to draw the text that should be on top of the image after the image is drawn. Try this code instead:

```
window.onload = function(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
         context.font = "40pt Calibri";
         context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);
     };
     imageObj.src = "darth-vader.jpg"; 
};
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hey jonas thanx for the reply ... is there any way that i can get the text above the image in the case i have mentioned above ... ???????

Comment: @RajeshRs: Yes, use a smaller value for the Y coordinate for the text.

Comment: @Jonas Hi Jonas, do u know how to put image on canvas image? is it possible?