# Trying to create a png file from txt input PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently learning code and I am making a little project for myself. I'm currently trying this project out with html5 and php. Here is what I want to do:

I want the user to input their info, like name, address, number, ect. Then I want to grab that info and somehow place it into a .png file so they can save that picture. I already have the code to grab the text, but I'm stuck on the next part.

Here is part of the code that I used to get the info:

```
$first = $_REQUEST['first'];
$last = $_REQUEST['last'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
```

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429011/how-to-write-the-text-on-top-of-image-in-html5-canvas

Comment: Here's a little article you can look at to understand it a bit better [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))

Comment: See [PNG creation with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php).