# How is it possible generate dynamic images for email based on user data like FirstName?

Tags: html, image, email

I don't know what this would kind of process would be called, which has been making Google searches and asking the right forum questions difficult. I did however find a service which does basically what I am looking to do.

https://niftyimages.com/PersonalizedImages

Let's take an example of a birthday email. I have a static image with a space for text. And I want to add the user's FirstName to the image. And then I want to serve that image to the user when they open the email.

What I can gather is that I need to have some kind of server-side service running which will take an HTTP-Request like http://examplesite.com/dynamicimage.jpg?firstname=Bob.

Based on that, it will render an image that displays "Happy Birthday, Bob" on the image.

I hope I am being clear. Any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could probably still use JavaScript (canvas) to generate the text onto an image. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp for example. Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8429496/752527

Comment: I get how this would work on a normal webpage, where a browser is executing the javascript. However, email is a different. There is no browser, just the email client. And I don't think email clients can execute javascript, can they? So the solution I think needs to run server side. There must be some kind of library or image server package that will do this, no?

Comment: You are 100% right. Seems like a service of some kind is what you need to generate this image of yours.